# React error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, in my  code looks like setData works fine and gives the fetched data to my state. However it doesn't work at fist render. But if I cahange something in the code website will be rendered again and country name is gonna show up on the screen just how I wanted.

But this error keeps popping up:
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'common')***

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Country() {
  const { countryName } = useParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(datas => setData(datas));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setCountry(data.find(a => a.name.common.toLowerCase() == countryName.replaceAll("-", " ")));
  }, [data])

  return (
    <>
      {
        <h1>{country.name.common}</h1>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Country
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `country.name` is `undefined` (and not an object with `common` property).

On initial render `country` is `{}` (an empty object).

So, `country.name` returns undefined.

And undefined does not have common property. Hence, the error.

So, a good rule of thumb before accessing a property would be to check if that property even exists.

```
<h1>{country?.name?.common}</h1>
```

Most of the time, you don't want to display tags if there is no data.

So, you would like to do something like this.

Markup after `&&` will be rendered only if expression before it, is truthy value.

```
{country?.name?.common && (
 <h1>{country.name.common}</h1>
)}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks, can I ask something else? What should I do if I want to check if I got the country? I mean I want to print to screen a lot of things like name, region etc.. Should I use eveytime: country?.name?.common &&... country?.region && ? Is there a shortcut for it? I mean I don't want to use it for every element of object.

Comment: `&&` and `?.`  both are actually shortcuts. You cannot use `if` inside `return`. So you can do something like `if(!country) return null` before your current `return`. Or you can use `?` operator inside return. `{country? (<h1>{country.name}</h1>): (<></>)}`

Comment: I got it now. Thank you vey much!

Answer (score 1):

As `country` initial value is an empty object, the `name` property will be undefined, which causes this error, You just need to set an initial value for name too, as an empty `object`

```
const [country, setCountry] = useState({ name: {} });
```

Full example of code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Country() {
  const { countryName } = useParams();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState({ name: {} });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(datas => setData(datas));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setCountry(data.find(a => a.name.common.toLowerCase() == countryName.replaceAll("-", " ")));
  }, [data])

  return (
    <>
      {
        <h1>{country.name.common}</h1>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Country
```

Or you can optionally chain the name property.

```
<h1>{country.name?.common}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I opened a new tab in Chrome and paste your api https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all and from the network tab, the results have some strange objects which do not have "name": {"common"....}

You have to filter these objects out

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I checked all and all of them had `name`

Comment: Sorry, i did not check them carefully

Comment: I don't only need name. I need to take the whole object of an country and use it in my html side of react.